# How to shimmer an input element?

Tags: html, css, forms

So there is one task assigned to me from my job.
We have to shimmer an input tag, I've searched CSS and found many and all of them were using :after :before for that, and hence input is self closing tag so it is not possible to use them in input.

So the question is, is there any other way to shimmer a button without using :after and :before, or any way for using :after and :before on input element?

This is the code example: https://github.com/shripalm/IntegrationStudio-Sitemap/blob/master/shimmerButtonTest.html

Comment: Could you describe more what is meant by shimmer in this instance. Is there for example a gif we could see. Also if there is any relevant code please include it direct in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help you. Sorrf if i false.
https://codepen.io/shswanson/pen/VwQKgE

```css
html {
  background-color: #333;
}

.button-container{
  color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 75px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 75px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: 100ms;
  -moz-transition: 100ms;
  -o-transition: 100ms;
  transition 100ms;
}

.button-container:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-transition: 100ms;
  -moz-transition: 100ms;
  -o-transition: 100ms;
  transition 100ms;
}

.button-text{
  width: 300px;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: 100; 
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.button-shimmer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: shimmer 6s infinite;
  -moz-animation: shimmer 6s infinite;
  animation: shimmer 6s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shimmer {
    0%   {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
      left: -5000px;
      top: 0px;
    }
  
    100% {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
      left: 5000px;
      top: 0px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes shimmer {
        0%   {
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */ 
            left: -5000px;
      top: 0px;}
}
      100% {
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            left: 5000px;
      top: 0px;}
}

@keyframes shimmer {
        0%   {
      background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
      background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
      left: -5000px;
      top: 0px;
    }
  
        100% { 
      background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
      background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
      left: 5000px;
      top: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<center>
<div class="button-container">
  <div class="button-text">Click Me!</div>
  <div class="background button-shimmer"></div>
</div>
</center
```

https://codepen.io/macshooo/pen/xrLGWa

```css
body { background: black; }

.error {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 25% auto;
  color: grey;
  background: none;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  font: bold 25px 'Open Sans';
  padding-right: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  &::before {
    content: '\00ab';
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: -20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  &:hover::before {
    padding-right: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}

.shimmer {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: translate3d(-120%,-50px,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg);
  transition: all 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.19,1,.22,1);
}

.error:hover{
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  .shimmer{
    transform: translate3d(120%,-100px,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="error">
  Shimmer Effect
  <div class="shimmer"></div>
</button>
```

input tag

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 0px;
  animation: fullView 0.5s forwards linear;
}

.br {
  border-radius: 8px;  
}

.w80 {
   width: 80%;
}

.card-box {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 0 #a9a9a9;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.Pic {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.comment {
  height: 10px;
  background: #777;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.animate {
   animation : shimmer 2s infinite;
   background: linear-gradient
   (to right, #eff1f3 4%, #e2e2e2 25%, #eff1f3 36%);
   background-size: 1000px 100%;
}

@keyframes fullView {
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: -1000px 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 1000px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card-box br">
   <div class="wrapper">
   <label>input tag</label>
      <input type="text" class="comment br animate w80" placeholder="input shimmer"/>
      <div class="comment br animate"></div>
      <div class="comment br animate"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is fine, but it's shimmer on div tag! we must have to shimmer on input tag..!